# Post hoc analysis for linear mixed model with nested effects

Tags: r, post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test, mixed-model, lsmeans

I'm having trouble in R with my Linear Mixed-Effects Model. I'm working with yeast in nectar. This is a part of my data just so you can see what is going on:
[image]

For the condition sucrose, I have 4 different samples (you can only see data for sample 4 here). For each sample I did 2 replica's (so `replica` is either 1 or 2). `sp` tells you which species it is and `condition` tells you whether the two yeast species were mixed together or just grew alone (single). I linked the two variables `condition` and `sp` together in `treatment`. `host` specifies the host plant of the species and `cells1` is the number of yeast cells.

It is the number of cells (`cells1`) that I want to compare for the different treatments. So I started off by making a mixed model with nested effects.

```
suc <- read.csv(file=file.choose(),header = TRUE,sep = ";")
attach(suc)
## load packages 'lme4', 'lsmeans', 'pbkrtest and 'Rcpp'
fit1 <- lmer(cells1~treatment+sp+treatment:sp+
    (1|cont/replica)+(1|replica/Sample)+(1|Sample/host), suc)
```

Next, I wanted to do a post hoc test. `TukeyHSD` wouldn't work. Error said something about not being able to use it with `lmer`. So after doing some research, I used the function `lsmeans`.

```
library("lsmeans")
lsmeans(fit1, pairwise~treatment, adjust="tukey")
```

When looking at the output, I get `NA` as outcome everywhere and I have no clue what is wrong or how to resolve this.
[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `treatment` variable represents the interaction between `condition` and `sp`, so putting `treatment` and `sp` in the model is redundant.  Since the difficulties you're having are with the fixed-effect model, you can diagnose/debug more simply by working with `lm()` until you can have a workable model.  I would try

```
 fit1 <- lm(cells1~condition*sp,data=suc)
```

(which is equivalent to a response of `~condition+sp+condition:sp`), check that all the parameters are estimated, and then move on to the mixed model.

Using `attach()` is often a bad idea.

I don't know what `cont` is.

Your random effect term should probably (?) be `1|Sample/replica` (i.e. replica nested within Sample). You may need to consider a random-slopes model, although it could be too difficult to fit.

Comment: I counted  the cells in 16 equal squares in a roster to get a correcter idea of how many there where. I indicate this with the variable 'cont'.

Answer (score 0):

I got the result I wanted by using the following commands:

```
suc$logcells <- log(Sucrose$cells1)
# load packages 'lmerTest', 'lsmeans', 'pbkrtest and 'Rcpp'
fit2 <- lmer(logcells~treatment + host + treatment:host +
                      (1|cont/replica)+(1|replica/Sample) + (1|Sample), 
             data=Sucrose)
summary(fit2)
anova(fit2)
ls_fit2 <- lsmeans(fit2, test.effs="treatment:host", adjust="Tukey")
ls_fit2
T_fit3 <- difflsmeans(fit2, test.effs="treatment:host", adjust="Tukey")
T_fit3
```

The main issues were that I first needed to transform my data logarithmically and that some commands did not work in combination with certain packages.

Comment: Well, OK, if you think those are the right results. But you did not use the lsmeans package at all, you used the lsmeans function in lmerTest. So you probably shouldn't have attached lsmeans.